# CMake Warning: Manually-specified variables were not used by the project in ROS 2

Tags: c++, cmake, ros2

This issue could be specific to ROS 2. I have defined a custom flag, say `HELLO_ROS`. Upon compilation, CMake throws the following warning:

```
$ colcon build --allow-overriding examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition --cmake-args -DHELLO_ROS=OFF
Starting >>> realsense2_camera_msgs
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
--- stderr: realsense2_camera_msgs
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    HELLO_ROS


---
Finished <<< realsense2_camera_msgs [4.43s]
Starting >>> realsense2_camera
Starting >>> realsense2_description
--- stderr: realsense2_description
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    HELLO_ROS


---
Finished <<< realsense2_description [0.69s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition [8.01s]
--- stderr: realsense2_camera
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    HELLO_ROS


---
Finished <<< realsense2_camera [15.5s]

Summary: 4 packages finished [20.1s]
  3 packages had stderr output: realsense2_camera realsense2_camera_msgs realsense2_description
```

Following are the packages in my workspace:

```
.
├── minimal_composition
└── realsense-ros
```

These packages are taken from [minimal_composition](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/foxy/rclcpp/composition/minimal_composition) and [realsense-ros](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/tree/ros2-beta). A minor modification as shown below is done in [publisher_node.cpp](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/355adf068fccd1b147acd89de62ad7d1bece9a78/rclcpp/composition/minimal_composition/src/publisher_node.cpp#L31-L37):

```
void PublisherNode::on_timer() {
  auto message = std_msgs::msg::String();

#ifdef HELLO_ROS
  message.data = "ON! " + std::to_string(count_++);
#else
  message.data = "OFF! " + std::to_string(count_++);
#endif

  RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Publisher: '%s'", message.data.c_str());
  publisher_->publish(message);
}
```

Similarly, [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/355adf068fccd1b147acd89de62ad7d1bece9a78/rclcpp/composition/minimal_composition/CMakeLists.txt#L20-L25) is modified as shown below:

```
add_library(composition_nodes SHARED
            src/publisher_node.cpp
            src/subscriber_node.cpp)

option(HELLO_ROS "Use HELLO_ROS" OFF) # OFF by default

if( HELLO_ROS ) 
target_compile_definitions(composition_nodes
  PRIVATE "MINIMAL_COMPOSITION_DLL"
  PRIVATE HELLO_ROS
)
else()
target_compile_definitions(composition_nodes
  PRIVATE "MINIMAL_COMPOSITION_DLL"
)
endif(HELLO_ROS)

ament_target_dependencies(composition_nodes rclcpp rclcpp_components std_msgs)
```

### Question

How to get rid of this warning?

### Version Info

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| CMake | 3.16.3 |
| GCC | 9.4.0 |
| ROS | Foxy |
| Ubuntu | 20.04.4 LTS |

### Update

So here is the analysis so far:

1. I removed `#else` from `#ifdef HELLO_ROS` and added `#if HELLO_ROS #else #endif` on the CPP file as shown below:

   ```
     std::string msg = std::to_string(count_++);

   #if HELLO_ROS
     msg += " HELLO_ROS is ON! ";
   #else
     msg += " HELLO_ROS is OFF! ";
   #endif

   #ifdef HELLO_ROS
     msg += " HELLO_ROS is DEFINED! ";
   #endif
     message.data = msg;
   ```
2. I removed `if/else` from `CMakeLists.txt` to convert it to the following way:

   ```
   target_compile_definitions(composition_nodes  PRIVATE "MINIMAL_COMPOSITION_DLL"  PRIVATE "HELLO_ROS=${HELLO_ROS}")
   ```
3. I selected only my package this time and compiled the whole workspace with the `--cmake-args -DHELLO_ROS=ON` argument.

**Observations:**

- Even though, the project was compiled with `-DHELLO_ROS=ON`, the `#if HELLO_ROS ***` got compiled to `#else`.
- Though, I can see that `#ifdef` is enabled.
- Furthermore, I can see that `HELLO_ROS` is set to ON inside CMakeLists.txt such as shown below:

  ```
  ./build/examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition/CMakeFiles/composition_nodes.dir/DependInfo.cmake:15:  "HELLO_ROS=ON"
  ./build/examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition/CMakeCache.txt:250://Use HELLO_ROS
  ./build/examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition/CMakeCache.txt:251:HELLO_ROS:BOOL=ON
  ```

Comment: I am not expect in ROS, but output "Summary: 4 packages finished" and "3 packages had stderr output: realsense2_camera realsense2_camera_msgs realsense2_description" suggests that you build not only **your package** (`examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition`) but also 3 other ones. And exactly building 3 **other packages** gives the warning. Building your package doesn't emit a warning.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Yes, you are right. There is no such warning, when I have only my package in the workspace. However, if there are other packages, this warning appears for every other packages. I guess, I should create a issue on their GitHub! I appreciate your kind answer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  I did some analysis to debug the issue and found confusing results. So may I request you kindly check the "Update" section on the post above?

Comment: Unlike to CMake, expression `ON` has no specifics when it is treated by the C **preprocessor**. The branch `#if ON` is not expanded: because `ON` doesn't exist as a **macro name**, it is treated by preprocessor as `0`. So having `"HELLO_ROS=${HELLO_ROS}"` as a parameter to `target_compile_definitions` has a little sense. For C preprocessor you need to define a macro to **integer** constant for use in `#if` directive. E.g. you could use `$<BOOL:${HELLO_ROS}>` [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), which is expanded either to 0 or 1

Comment: For the future: when debug some problem, try to eliminate as many **unrelated aspects** as you can. E.g. if you unsure how **CMake** evaluates `if( HELLO_ROS )` command, then you could add a call to `message` inside that branch: looking into output you can check your expectations **without C code**. If you unsure how C **compiler** interprets `#if HELLO_ROS` in case it `HELLO_ROS` is `ON`, then **do not use CMake conditionals**. Instead. explicitly pass `HELLO_ROS=ON` as a parameter to `target_compile_definitions` and check behavior of C code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks a lot. Thanks for referring to the cmake-generator-expressions. It works well! I am noting down your suggestions on an efficient debugging process. Thanks again.